# Folder in DB Schema

Tags: mysql, database-design, schema, directory

From the following simple schema:

```
TABLE users
id
fname
lname

TABLE assets
id
userid (fk users.id)
assetname
assetdesc
```

Which would be the recommended way of created "folders" or "groups" for assets. I would also apply this to MESSAGES and other types that might make use of being organized in a folder-like structure.

Answer (score 2):

add two other tables:

one for the 'folder'

```
folder
-------
id
name
```

and one for the contents

```
folder_content
--------------
folder_id
asset_id
```

Comment: Right now I'm essentially querying "give me all assets that belong to users.id 3" ... but if assets are to be in a Folder, the query changes. However, not all assets will be in a folder... or is it best to at least be in a default folder?